# How do I run both these turtle scripts one after another

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, pyscripter

```
import random
import turtle
spiral = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.bgcolor("black")


spiral.color("cadet blue")

randomfive = random.randint(5,15)
spiral.pensize(randomfive)

randomfour = random.randint(20,75)
spiral.speed (randomfour)
randomthree = random.randint(200,500)

randomtwo = random.randint(5,20)


random = random.randint(10,360)

spiral.pendown()

for i in range(randomthree):
    spiral.forward(i * randomtwo)
    spiral.right(random)





def christmas ():
    turtle.bgcolor("black")
    for i in range(2):
        turtle.speed (9999999)
        coordone = random.randint (-300,300)
        coordtwo = random.randint (-300,300)
        right = random.randint (1,360)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto (coordone,coordtwo)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.right(right)
        for y in range (10):
            turtle.speed(9999)
            turtle.right(36)
            for x in range (50):
                turtle.color("red")
                turtle.speed(99999)
                turtle.pensize(x/5)
                turtle.forward (x-(x-1))
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto (coordone,coordtwo)
            turtle.pendown()
        turtle.right(18)
        for z in range (10):
            turtle.speed(9999)
            turtle.right(36)
            for w in range (50):
                turtle.color("green")
                turtle.speed(99999)
                turtle.pensize(w/3)
                turtle.forward (w-(w-1))
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto (coordone,coordtwo)
            turtle.pendown()
christmas()
```

When I try this python says "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'" (By the way, this is the whole code). Please help with this issue. The name of this is droplets.py so that wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Don't call your variables `random`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
import random

def spiral():
    turtle.bgcolor("black")

    spiral = turtle.Turtle()

    spiral.color("cadet blue")

    randomfive = random.randint(5, 15)
    spiral.pensize(randomfive)

    randomfour = random.randint(0, 11)
    spiral.speed(randomfour)

    randomthree = random.randint(200, 500)

    randomtwo = random.randint(5, 20)

    randomone = random.randint(10, 360)

    spiral.pendown()

    for i in range(randomthree):
        spiral.forward(i * randomtwo)
        spiral.right(randomone)

    spiral.penup()


def christmas():
    turtle.bgcolor("black")
    turtle.speed("fastest")

    for i in range(2):
        coordinate = random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-300, 300)
        right = random.randint(1, 360)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(coordinate)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.right(right)

        for y in range(10):
            turtle.right(36)
            for x in range(50):
                turtle.color("red")
                turtle.pensize(x / 5)
                turtle.forward(1)
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(coordinate)
            turtle.pendown()

        turtle.right(18)

        for z in range(10):
            turtle.right(36)
            for w in range(50):
                turtle.color("green")
                turtle.pensize(w / 3)
                turtle.forward(1)
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(coordinate)
            turtle.pendown()

spiral()
christmas()

turtle.done()
```